# Get internal IP of pod that is being killed in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to get the internal IP of a pod that is being killed. What I do now is to subscribe to events with reason "Killing" that have an "involvedObject" that is of type "Pod". If so I try to retrieve the pod to get its IP. The problem (I think) is that the Pod is already killed by the time I make the request to get it so I cannot its IP this way (this approach works fine when reason is "Created").

Is there a way to get the internal IP of a pod that is being stopped/killed before it's actually removed by Kubernetes?

**Update**

What I try to do is to implement a Kubernetes service discovery module (A) for [Turbine](https://github.com/Netflix/Turbine) to detect all of the pods that expose [Hystrix streams](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-metrics-event-stream). I use [fabric8 k8s library](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/tree/master/components/kubernetes-api) to watch for Kubernetes events. When an event is discovered by A to be a pod running with label "hystrix-stream" I load the pod details (using the fabric8 library) in order to the get internal IP to the pod. This IP is then sent to Turbine so that it subscribes to the hystrix stream. This works great! The problem is that when A discovers that a pod is being killed I cannot load the pod details since by that time the pod has already been removed. Thus I cannot get the IP of the pod and I cannot tell Turbine to unsubscribe from this pod. My workaround is to maintain state in A that maps the pod name to its IP address. So what I'm after is a way to avoid maintaining this state in A and instead ask Kuberentes for the IP address of a pod that is being killed.

Comment: When you say 'get the IP', do you mean, from the client?  Expose it into a container in a pod?

Comment: What do you mean by client? I have an app that is interested in the internal IP of every pod tagged with a certain label. On match the app subscribes to an event stream exposed by each (labelled) pod. What I'm trying to solve now is for the app to automatically unsubscribe from the stream when a (labelled) pod is being stopped.

Comment: what you describe is what I meant by 'from the client'.  Answer coming.

Answer (score 2):

Johan-

You can watch the pods resource to get add/update/remove events for them. http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/api-reference/v1/operations.html, search for 'list or watch objects of kind Pod'.  Hope that helps.

Note, events above does not refer to the Event API resource, but rather watch events.

Comment: Yes this is what I already do. But if the pod is in "Killing" state I can't get it's IP. The internal IP is (afaict) is not present in the event when the pod is being killed.

Comment: I think I'm missing something -- if what you're trying to do is 'unsubscribe from the [event] stream', why do you need the pod's IP for that?

Comment: I've updated the questions with some clarifications (hopefully)